# Fetch all app IDs I am an admin of

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to fetch a list of the Opengraph and Graph apps that my account is an admin of. I cannot find documentation to perform such a task. Is this possible?

I am developing a tool to fetch tokens dynamically (which we will then use to make user-generated posts later). Currently, I have to paste in the AppID manually. I would like to make a dropdown of the current list of available apps to perform this task.

Edit~ This page of FB documentation suggests you can of course fetch a lot of information about an individual Application when you already have its applicationID: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

Instead, I would develop roughly this: 'Facebook, I have the access_token for this developer account, for which apps is this developer account an administrator' Response: 'AppID1, AppID2, AppID9'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the lists of apps a use is a developer on by hitting

```
 /me/applications/developer/
```

or using the `app_role` FQL table with  following query

```
select application_id from developer where developer_id = xxxxxxxxx
```

Thanks to [davek804](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users/1231943/davek804) for the query

Comment: I will start testing this now and approve the answer if it gets me the data I need. Thanks!

Comment: Using the FQL tool on Facebook with my access token works very well. It returns the list of application IDs. I am satisfied that this will give me the result I need when I turn it into a query in our java server code. I'll mark this as correct even though I have not fully implemented it yet - I've seen the needed results.

Comment: I used this query: select application_id from developer where developer_id = xxxxxxxxx

Comment: is there a way to convert this FQL query into a web service? If not, I will just write the FQL query into my application.